# Creating an incremental load in Azure Data Factory with a group by clause

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I have the following SQL statement:

```
Select max(id) as id, device_id, max(current_value) as value, 
RoundTimeUp(Store_time,15) as Displaydate
from table
group by device_id, RoundTimeUp(Store_time,15)
```

RoundTimeUp is a function that rounds the [store_time] to the next quarter hour, i.e. 14:04 -> 14:15, 19:43 -> 19:45 etc.

When I try to create the same query s an incremental load in the Data Factory,
I modify the sample statement statement to this statement:

```
$$Text.Format('select max([id]) as [id], device_id, 
max([current_value]) as value, [dbo].[RoundtimeUp](Store_time,15) as 
DisplayDate from table
where store_time >= \'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}\' AND 
store_time < \'{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}\'
group by device_id, RoundtimeUp(Store_time,15)', WindowStart, WindowEnd)
```

however, I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid Token: (Sql-statement), at 1, 13 at Oopc.Generated.Tokenizer 2.NextToken() at Oopc.Generated.ShiftReduceParser 4.Parse(ITokenizer 1 tokenizer) at Microsoft.DataPipeline.MacroLanguage.MacroRuntime.Evaluate(String expression, IDictionary 2 localVariables).

If I made any typos in the SQL-code now, the SQL-statement works perfectly fine without the macro expression. A regular select statement also works, as long as the macro expression is at the end. 
How do I get this statement to work? Do I need to add a second $$Text with the group by?

Comment: Please provide an actual SQL query produced as a result of the `Format` function

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here, there is no format function. The only function there is is RoundtimeUp which is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Should it be `\\'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}\\'` (double backslash)? MS examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-json-scripting-reference#azure-sql-database

Comment: The "designer" only shows one Backslash, the "author and deploy" tab uses double backslashes.  (see imgur link)
However, I am unable to add a "Group by" clause AFTER the time, as I don't understand the syntax how to add it, regardless of double or single backslashes.

http://imgur.com/a/wr1tD